# What does TBSCAN GENROW mean in Explain Plan?

Tags: db2, explain

In a DB2 Explain Plan, what does `TBSCAN GENROW` (line 5 below) mean?

```
SELECT STATEMENT ( Estimated Costs =  1.811E+03 [timerons] )
   1 RETURN
      2 NLJOIN
          3 [O] TBSCAN
              4 SORT
                  5 TBSCAN GENROW
          6 [I] FETCH EKKO
              7 IXSCAN EKKO~1 #key columns:  2
```

The [IBM docs](http://webdocs.caspur.it/ibm/udb-6.1/db2help/index.htm#cncpve) say `GENROW` is

> "A built-in function that generates a
>   table of rows, using no input from
>   tables, indexes, or operators"

What does that mean from a performance perspective?

Also, this is in an SAP system if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.  `GENROW` means it's creating a temporary table which is then joined to an actual table.  This is usually done when the query contains an `IN (...)` statement.  Specific to SAP, this is usually done for `FOR ALL ENTRIES` queries.

Comment: Interesting... 

But... the question - what's the actual performance impact?

Comment: In SQL Server, it would mean creating a row that doesn't come from a table